# Check another column to determine the kind of calculation to perform

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have a spread sheet which, among other things, has a table with a row that specifies the type of problem (put in numbers 0 to 4, according to a reference table) that occurred, and the column next to it says how long it took to be solved. The things is, the problems are not sorted by type, so I can't perform a regular SUM, MEDIAN, etc... on a range. It looks something like this:

```
Problem type | Time taken 
      0      |     143 
      3      |     123 
      2      |     987 
      0      |     431
```

And so on. The options I see are either composing 5 new tables by error type, or make

```
= function IF (*totalSumRange*; "cellToTheLeft == errorTypeNumber")
```

kind of statements, but I apparently can't specify such things within the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AVERAGEIF` in Google Sheets, per below. (Similarly for `SUMIF`.)

[image: Google Sheets AverageIf Example]

You can either specify the exact range, as above (`A$2:A$8`), or generalise the parameters to `A:A, D2, B:B`. I prefer the latter as the formula doesn't need to be updated when new entries are added to columns A and B. However, this assumes there is no other data further down in columns A and B.

For reference, from [Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en):

> `AVERAGEIF(criteria_range, criterion, [average_range])`
>
> - `criteria_range` - The range to check against criterion.
> - `criterion` - The pattern or test to apply to criteria_range.
>
>   - Equals: `"text"` or `1` or `"=text"` or `"=1"`
>   - Greater than: `">1"`
>   - Greater than or equal to: `">=1"` Less than: `"<1"` Less than or equal to: `"<=1"`
>   - Not equal to: `"<>1"` or `"<>text"`
> - `average_range` - [ OPTIONAL ] - The range to average. If not included, `criteria_range` is used for the average instead.